# Bootstrap panel shows on all tabs?

Tags: bootstrap-modal

In my "About the API" tab, content will not show once I open the modal until selecting another tab and reverting back to it. What code am I missing here to fix this?

```
<div class="tab-content">
   <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade active" id="aboutTab">
      <p>
         <div></div>
         A simple and interactive web map application created by the
         technical resources team showing information regarding each
         IRVM project in the state of Maryland.
      </p>
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
         <div class="panel-heading">Web Application Features</div>
         <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item">Export out drawn features for use in other
               programs</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Address locator for finding specific locations
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Measurement tool for finding length, area and
               other properties</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Bookmarking for saving important sites</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">
               Print page option for saving out display in different
               formats
            </a>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item">
               Layer switching between different basemaps and overlay
               data
            </a>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="contactTab">
      <p>
         <div></div>
         This application is intended to be as informative and
         user-friendly as possible. Contact us to report changes,
         concerns, or other feedback.
         <font color="blue">
            <a
               href="mailto:LResh@sha.state.md.us?subject=LOD Website Feedback -Enter Your Name-">Send an email</a>
         </font>
         .
      </p>
   </div>
   <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="disclaimerTab">
      <p>
         <div></div>
         <font color="red">
            The data provided on this site is for informational and
            planning purposes only.
            <br></br>
            Absolutely no accuracy or completeness guarantee is implied
            or intended. All information on this map is subject to such
            variations and corrections as might result from a complete
            title search and/or accurate field survey.
         </font>
      </p>
   </div>
   <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="exportTab">
      <p>
         <div></div>
         This web application exports drawn features in a geojson
         format. Future updates will hopefully allow downloads into
         other data types.
         <br></br>
         <font color="red">
            <b>***</b>
            Note that features created using the measuring tool will not
            be extracted from export. Circular features are exported out
            as their long/lat center points.
            <b>***</b>
         </font>
      </p>
      <p>
         To learn more about limits/structure for .json files
         <a href="https://macwright.org/2015/03/23/geojson-second-bite.html"
            target="_blank">
            <font color="blue"> click here
         </a>
      </font>
         .
      </font>
      </p>
      <p>
         <b>In order to convert your .json files to .KMZ files or
            another format, use </b>
         <a href="http://geojson.io/#map=2/20.0/0.0" target="_blank">
            <font color="blue">GeoJson.io
         </a>
      </font>
         <b>.
      </p>
   </b>
   </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lresh/prpz0L6y/

Comment: Some of your tags are misaligned (<a><font></a></font>)

Comment: Also an extra unmatched `</font>` after 'learn more about limits...'. Also an extra  unmatched `<b>` in the very next para. Also `<div></div>` inside `<p>` is illegal, I think.  First thing I'd try is to fix up your HTML - use a validator.